# Python for loop only committing last line of data to SQLite3 table - need all lines committed

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite

I am currently pulling data out of an SQLite3 database which contains 4 tables in total: "intra_day", "closing_price", "vol_" and "intra_day2". I wish to extract the data from 3 tables by date, parse it in a certain way, reformat the lines of data, and then plug it back into the 4th table.

I am creating 2 cursors, one to extract the data, and one to insert it back in (this may be the incorrect way to do this)

```
import sqlite3
import time
import datetime

conn = sqlite3.connect('stu3.sqlite3', detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES|sqlite3.PARSE_COLNAMES)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT intra_day.date, intra_day.time, intra_day.price, closing_price.cprice, vol_.vol FROM intra_day, closing_price, vol_ WHERE intra_day.date = closing_price.date AND vol_.date = intra_day.date')
conn2 = sqlite3.connect('stu3.sqlite3', detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES|sqlite3.PARSE_COLNAMES)
cur2 = conn2.cursor()
```

I then parse the extracted data as follows:

```
for row in cur:
    date_intra, time_intra, price_intra, cprice, vol = (row[0], row[1], float(row[2]), float(row[3]), float(row[4]))

    dt_intra = datetime.datetime.strptime('{} {}'.format(date_intra.partition(' ')[0], time_intra),'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    nline = dt_intra, price_intra, cprice, vol

    cur2.execute('INSERT INTO intra_day2 (date, price, price2, vol) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)',
    (nline))
    conn.commit()
```

It only seems to be committing the last "nline" instead of the 200K+ lines of data that get extracted and parsed.

Do I have my INSERT function indented wrong?

I have tried a couple of variations and I either get nothing committed to the intra_day2 table, or just one line (which I assume is the last line in the data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a single connection.

Close both cursors before committing the transaction.
(All of this should be done after the loop.)

Comment: Lovely - ok so I have deleted the indented conn.commit(), and added "cur.close()" and "cur2.close()" outside the loop at the end. Should I commit the conn or the conn2? Or both? Apologies, I have only been learning this stuff for a couple of months....

Comment: Only one connection has changes to commit.

Comment: And so that would be the "conn2" as it is "cur2" which executes the "INSERT" request? I'm sorry if that seems like such an obvious question...

Comment: Ive just noticed you said "use a single connection" - thanks will do that now!

Answer (score 1):

First, you should declare a transaction. I'm not sure which library and language you're using, but the equivalent in SQL would be `BEGIN TRANSACTION`. Do that outside of your loop. Then, loop all the inserts, and after your loop, do your `conn.commit()`.

Comment: Gosh sorry I forgot to mention I am using Python...!!

Comment: So I place the "BEGIN TRANSACTION;" above the "for row in row" and then unindent the "conn.commit()" above?

Comment: Python [tries to be clever about transactions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#controlling-transactions).

Comment: @user3253628 Yes, that is correct (if unindending means "outside the loop" for python.)